# Using Jenkins to compile a Maven pom.xml for a bukkit plugin and trying to use Sonar

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

So basically I've had my Jenkins, sonar, and maven set up working before but I had to take like a 6 month break and I've come back after making some changes to my code only to find that My sonar won't work.

### Error

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>   ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
>   ERROR: Caused by: com/persistit/ClassIndex
>   ERROR: Caused by: com.persistit.ClassIndex

### Jenkins output

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: com/persistit/ClassIndex
ERROR: Caused by: com.persistit.ClassIndex
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e   switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE

### versions

sonar 3.6
jenkins 1.525
maven 2.2.1
mysql 5.5.32

Best way to check look in your Avast Virus Chest to see if it stole the file ClassIndex.class out of the jar named at this time for sonar version 3.6

> akiban-persistit-3.2.7.jar

easiest way to fix is to use 7zip, or winrar or something similar to open up the jar file.
Step 1) have avast extract it to the desktop it should be in com\persistit\ClassIndex.class

Step 2) navigate to your sonar directory then go to \war\sonar-server\WEB-INF\lib  and open up the akiban-persistit-3.2.7.jar file with the for-mentioned programs

step 3) navigate in the jar file to com\persistit\ and copy over the ClassIndex.class file from your desktop save the jar and close out.

step 4) open avast, click summary, click the file system shield, click on settings, then click the exclusions tab and add in your sonar installation folder.

you should now be good to go.

Comment: Can't you check the log file of sonar under the logs directory?

Comment: I didn't notice anything wrong with the log file for sonar but I've attached it at the bottom of my post @KugathasanAbimaran

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out it was Avast it just stole the class file out of the jar and stored it in the virus chest. Which is why It probably threw that error instead of like a jar missing error.

Comment: Updated it to show how it was solved.